# What is the fastest way to load compressed images on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opengl-es, jpeg

I am writing an iOS app which need to load a lot of full-screen size images into OpenGL. Image storage space is a concern, so I am using png or jpg. Problem is: Loading the image data takes way too long (100s of ms on an iPad2).

I was wondering if someone knows the fastest way to load good-quality compressed image data on an iPad or similar? This could include switching to different image compression formats (?)

Here's what I've found:

- Loading jpg via the iOS implementation of libturbo-jpeg is faster than any way I found for png.
- If you split jpg images in two, you can parallel-decompress via GCD which almost cuts the load time in half. Still not enough!
- The PowerVR compressed PVRTC format can be loaded very quickly, but both compression ratio and image quality are way outside what I need...
- No idea how jpeg-2000 would perform, but it seems to be optimized for compression ratio rather than decoding speed.

Any ideas?? This must be a common problem for games or similar..

Are there any newer image formats (jpg is 1986!!) which have portable implementation, maybe slightly less compression than jpg, but decode much faster?

Comment: I like your parallel decompress! I use the turbo lib too. Fastest would be save prerendered decompressed tiles and CATiled layers to show them. No image decompression at all. People doing this with PhotoScroller code as starting point.

Comment: Hmm, I have more or less random access to the images, so decompressing beforehand won't work for me, I guess.. There just must be something inbetween PVRTC (20 ms load time, ugly) and jpg (200 ms, nice)...

Comment: Most of the applications I know rely on PVRTC for the textures they supply, unless those textures need to be generated at runtime. Have you tried out the various compression options in PVRTexTool ( http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp ) to see if you can achieve an acceptable image quality?

Comment: When you say "random access to the images" - so you access them on the phone or via downloading? If downloading can look at PhotoScrollerNetwork, which downloads jpegs and decodes them using libjpegturbo in real time.

Comment: @Brad: I have tried a good number of combinations. But maybe I should check out PVRTC again and see whether I can get better quality out of it.

Comment: @David: The images are in compressed form on the iPad disk, but the whole thing is downloaded (so not part of the distribution). I was not aware of PhotoScrollerNetwork though - let me check it out and see whether it's faster.

Comment: @Paul Did you get anywhere on this? Would be interesting to hear what you ended up using.

Comment: Make the sequence if images into an H.264 video.

Answer (score 2):

This library might help you out:

https://github.com/path/FastImageCache